# generate pdf of a whole layout in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to save the whole layout as a pdf attachement on clicking a button in my sample application. 
Please let me know if some urls are there to resolve my issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: By programmatic  you can capture that layout image and further you can use to attach this.

Comment: can u suggest me with some urls ??? @kitkat

Comment: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/05/android-itext-pdf-bluetooth-printer.html

Comment: Please check it  and customize according to your need 
.
http://karanbalkar.com/2013/05/tutorial-22-generate-pdf-using-droidtext-in-android/